# Yii2 DropDownList with full names

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to populate a dropwdown list in Yii2 with the person's full name, the first and last name are in my DB in different columns.

in my Person table

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- dep_id (fk)

...

In my Person.php model I have

```
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

This is my helper function to get back the full name in GridViews and works fine. But I'm having trouble populating the dropdown.

```
    // Get person
    $person = Person::find()
                ->orderBy('last_name')
                ->asArray()
                ->all();

    // Person drop down
    $personMap = ArrayHelper::map($person, 'fullName', 'dep_id');
```

with that I get nothing in the dropdown list, but the person IDs are correct. So how would I need to go about this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `ArrayHelper::map()` like that because `fullName` is not presented in model attributes.

But you can specify the closure instead of attribute name to achieve desired result:

```
$person = Person::find()
    ->orderBy('last_name')               
    ->all();

$personMap = ArrayHelper::map(
    $person,
    function ($person, $defaultValue) {
        return $person->getFullName();
    }
    'dep_id'
);
```

If you apply `asArray()`, you won't be able to call model methods, but you still can include full name like so:

```
$person = Person::find()
    ->orderBy('last_name')               
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

$personMap = ArrayHelper::map(
    $person,
    function ($person, $defaultValue) {
        return $person['first_name'] . ' ' . $person['last_name'];
    }
    'dep_id'
);
```

I don't recommend to use that since it's duplicating logic of getting full name.

As for details: in `map()` method for both `$from` and `$to` parameters `getValue()` method will be called(). And if you check [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue%28%29-detail) for that method, you will find some examples of specifying `$key` as closure.

Also usually such lists are formed vice versa: string variables indexed by ids.

In this case you can pass it as `$items` for displaying [drop-down list](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail).

And in your case there are might be some problems when models set contains at least two persons with exact same name.

To change that just simply switch second and third parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
//use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


//use app\models\Users;


//replace lastname with field you want to order by in your database  table

$person = Users::find()

->orderBy('LastName')               

->all();

$personMap = ArrayHelper::map(

    $person,'UserID',


    function ($person, $defaultValue)

       {
        return $person->getFullName();
      }

          );

       ?>
//replace UserID 

    <?= $form->field($model, 'UserID')->dropDownList(
$personMap, ['prompt'=>'[--select person--]',
        ]) 
?>  

//get getFullname function should placed in your model 

function getFullName()
{
     return $this->FirstName."".$this->LastName;
    }
//Firstname and lastname are the fields in your database
```